# Heroku Cant Find main class : MainView

Tags: java, maven, heroku

When deploying my maven application to heroku, I get the error mesage:

app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class MainView

My procfile path matches the classpath in my manifest (procfile below), so I am unsure why it can't find the class.

> web: java -cp target/classes/com/vaadin/app MainView

I am deploying the app with 'git push heroku master', the build succeeds on heroku but gives the above error after building.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.vaadin.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>wonderapp</artifactId>
    <name>Wonderapp</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <vaadin.version>13.0.5</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <!-- Maven central - reduces first-time build time -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>

        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
             <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
             <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository needed for prerelease versions of Vaadin -->
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- Maven central - reduces first-time build time -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <!-- Repository needed for prerelease versions of Vaadin -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-charts-flow</artifactId>
            </dependency>

<!-- I added this -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.26.2</version>
            </dependency>
<!-- I added this -->


            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added to provide logging output as Flow uses -->
        <!-- the unbound SLF4J no-operation (NOP) logger implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JavaFX depencdency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JavaFX depencdency -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Here for hopefully heroku to work  -->
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
              </plugin>


<!--  heroku maven plugin -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.26.2</version>
            </plugin>

<!--  heroku maven plugin -->

            <!-- Jetty plugin for easy testing without a server -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.11.v20180605</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode can be activated with either property or profile -->
            <id>production-mode</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>vaadin.productionMode</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>


            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-production-files</goal>
                                    <goal>package-for-production</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Any help is appreciated.